# Is there a way of adding emails to a case from within MS Outlook

Tags: email, case, email2case

Is there a way to add an email to an existing case easily from within Outlook? I am using MS Outlook 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce for Outlook won't do this - you can only create a new case. I'm pretty sure you'll need to go for a paid integration to get this functionality. There are a few Outlook integrations on the AppExchange - [LinkPoint](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001qTIuEAM) is one that I have heard consistently good reviews of, though I've not ever implemented it myself.

Answer (score -1):

I believe Salesforce for Outlook will meet your needs.  It allows you to attach emails to many different objects, including cases.  I just tested with MS Outlook 2010 and it's working great!

A few wrinkles: 
It looks at the email address in the From field, and if it doesn't find a contact or lead in your Salesforce org, it won't display anything (In that case, you'll have to do a search instead).  If it does find a match, it will display related records (including cases), and you can click the + email icon to add the email to the case.

It adds the email as a task, not within the Emails related list.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was looking to add email to EXISTING case, your solution does not clearly state how this can be achieved unfortunately.

Comment: Hi Bartley, it does add the email to an existing case, but does so as a Task, not in the Emails related list.